# temporal filtering and their concepts in image/signal/video processing

Tags: image-processing, filter, signal-processing, video-processing

I am completely new to Image processing. I am confused by temporal filtering and its concepts. I am eager to know, for instance, what is the difference between gaussian temporal filtering and gaussian filtering when both of them are applied to a sequence of frames in real-time?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gaussian filtering is a low pass filtering, which means it blurs the signal, attenuating its high frequency components.

Gaussian spatial filtering (applied on an image) will blur the image, smoothing out rapid variations like strong edges.

Gaussian temporal filtering (applied on a sequence of images) will blur the sequence evolution, smoothing out the temporal variation, like a rapid variation in illumination or movement of an object. It's a gaussian filtering of the signal obtained by the temporal evolution of each single pixel.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I came up with one more question..is this explanation correct that, we have two version of each kind of filtering alogorithms. one is without "temporal" which is used for image filtering and one with "Temporal" which is used for a sequence of frames.. is that correct?

Comment: You can take any spatial filter (gaussian, average, median, sharpening, etc) and use it for temporal filtering. It only depends on what values you apply the filter to.

Comment: so you mean, "gaussian temporal filtering" is exactly "gaussian filtering" but applied to a sequence of frames?

Comment: Exactly. You filter with a Gaussian kernel, but the signal being processed isn't the image (spatial filtering) but a sequence of pixel values taken in temporal order. Of course you have to do this for every pixel of the frame, so for an M x N image you will need to filter N*M temporal signals, each of them as long as the temporal sequence

Comment: is it possible to apply a temporal filtering algorithm(like median) just into a certain pixel in a sequence of frames?

Comment: Yes, you just filter a sequence of that pixel values over the whole sequence

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41525/discussion-between-ghembo-and-user2758510)